# Does momentum being conserved when there is conversion of kinetic energy (for example heat) violates the law of physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

The Conservation Of Momentum says that in a isolated system the total momentum is always same this is because the momentum splits up because of Newtons third law and the acceleration is very less to notice. But in every situation there is energy conservation in form of sound, heat and etc.
If some of the energy is converted to another form than the kinetic energy should decrease so the momentum should also decrease. This means that momentum should also decrease. But The Law of Conservation Of momentum says it must be equal. However if Both conservation of Momentum and Conservation of energy are true when there is energy conversion, then wouldn't energy law be violated

Comment: *"Also The Conservation Of Momentum says that in a isolated system the total momentum is always same this is because the momentum splits up because of Newtons third law and the acceleration is very less to notice."* Huh??

Comment: *This means Momentum and Kinetic Energy are directly related. So what is the purpose of momentum then.* This is a *non sequitur*. Even when two concepts are related, each can have its own conceptual importance. (Another example of this: space and time in Special Relativity.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Momentum is a vector (with a direction) whereas kinetic energy is a scalar (no direction).
2. Momentum is linear in the velocities but kinetic energy is quadratic.
3. Total momentum is conserved but not necessarily total kinetic energy (although total energy — which is not the same as kinetic energy - is conserved).

In fact in elastic collisions (where kinetic energy is conserved), conservation of energy provides an extra condition that further restricts the possible momenta compatible with conservation of momentum.

For instance, if you start with $\vec p_1+\vec p_2$, there are infinitely many vectors $\vec p_3$ and $\vec p_4$ so that
$$
\vec p_1+\vec p_2=\vec p_3+\vec p_4\,. \tag{1}
$$
If you now insist that the collision be elastic, then only a subset of $\vec p_3$ and $\vec p_4$ will be compatible with (1) *and* the conservation of kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

If an object loses kinetic energy in a collision , it will conserve the momentum

> Momentum can only happen when there is velocity. And when there is velocity there is kinetic energy. This means Momentum and Kinetic Energy are directly related.

Both happen at same time because it involves the velocity factor in it but they are not directly related as momentum is a vector and kinetic energy is a scalar quantity its like how Force and pressure have acceleration in them but vary depending on their meanings.

Momentum is always conserved even though some energy is lost via Transfer of heat

Comment: "If an object loses kinetic energy , it is not necessary to lose its momentum": this is only true if the mass of the object changes, because if the speed goes down and the mass is the same, then $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$ definitely changes.  "Momentum is always conserved" is a statement that needs qualification, because it depends on a choice of system and if there are external forces present.

Comment: oh i meant momentum to be conserved and if kinetic energy to be lost in collisions (inelastic) thanks for pointing out my blunder

Comment: and yes if there is no external force the momentum is conserved